How can I make an Amiibo from an NFC card?
For Christmas, I got an NFC reader/writer for my PC, and about a dozen NTAG215 tags. I found this Amiibo Database on GitHub, but I found out the NFC files alone aren't enough for my New Nintendo 3DS XL to recognize it. How can I get an NFC card to work like an Amiibo?
The app I'm using to write information into my card is NFC Tools by Wakdev.

If someone could create and add 'NFC' and 'Amiibo' as a tag to my question for me, that would be great.

We have a tag for near-field-communication. Adding NFC as synonym requires an  answer score of 5 or more on the tag. Presently we don't have any answers to questions on the topic, so it's probably something that requires a mod.

You shouldn't need to do anything more than writing the NFC file to your tag. Does it not work at all? Like what happens when you try to scan it using your 3DS, nothing at all or does it give you some error?

@Charanor When I put information of… let’s say Luigi from Smash onto the tag, the Smash Bros. game says, “This is not an amiibo supported by Super Smash Bros.” To test if I am just using an Amiibo not supported by the game, I go to Amiibo settings on the device, and there it says, “The device you used is not an amiibo figure.”

Try placing the NFC tag directly against 3DS in various places /angles; in particular, try directly on the screen and flat against the back of the 3DS.

@Alex I am not familiar with Amiibos specifically but from a quick search it seems that Super Smash Bros are quite picky with their Amiibos, some characters require the figurine (Which would be the .bin files from that GitHub page) and some characters only need the tag (and some can do either). I would try with a few different characters that you know for sure should work with the tag (there is an Amiibo wiki somewhere with this info) and report back if none of them work.

I found something out.  I am trying to but the files onto my NFC tag, but all it is doing is putting the link on it, not the NFC files. I need either a way to get NFC Tools to put the correct information I need, or a different app or tool that will save files for me.
